# NodeJS Как установить и запустить язык программирования Cat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Ещё когда-то давно занимался переводом статьи, посвященной языку программирования Cat, недавно захотелось попробовать его наконец-то, нашёл оффициальной репозиторий https://github.com/cdiggins/cat-language , однако я совершенно не понял, что с этим делать. Я пытался запустить файл cat.js при помощи nodeJS.

```
node cat.js
```

Однако это ни чему не привело, возможно кто-то сможет подсказать как правильно?

Comment: Насколько я понял, вам надо подключить cat.js к какому нибудь проекту на node.js, потом использовать модуль `CatLanguage`.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, вам надо установить `cat` через `npm`, на каком-нибудь проекте на `node.js`, потом использовать модуль `CatLanguage`.

Например:

```
var ce = new CatLanguage.CatEvaluator();
ce.eval("6 7 dup mul sub");
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: @CoffeeinTime ну как, получилось? Если мой ответ правильный - отметьте его как правильный :)